# Finding lines that end with zero and print its sister line

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have files with lines such as:

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData1;200
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData1;200

Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0

Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

Basically Every 2 lines are related to each other. Im trying to find the best way to only print the lines with a single 0 and the line above or below it. So the output would be like.

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0

Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR%3!=0{f=$NF;a=$0;getline;if(f==0||$NF==0)print a"\n"$0"\n"}' file
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0

Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

Comment: Probably not a problem to the OP, just noting that this will break if the records are separated by more than one line or there is an empty line at the top of the file because of the modulo. Not very elegant, I fail to see how this is better than the perl solution.

Comment: Definitely not a problem, the OP states pairs of lines, nowhere is it mentioned about leading newlines.. There is no need to list the infinite other factors that are unrelated to the question that will also break this solution. Whether you think this solution is elegant or not is also beside the point, stop crying because the OP didn't choose your answer.

Comment: I reason this worked over the perl answer is because the lines have have date and time and since its not specific enough. When i run my file against perl its printing everyline. I did have to make a modification to the awk answer. it needed NR%4 but with that it is able to find ever line that has a zero after the last semi colon. The perl works only if theirs no zeros in any of the data up to the last semi colon.

Comment: @sudo_O if you're going to suggest people use getline, please warn them about the many inherent, completely non-obvious dangers so they get a clue what kind of issues they will face in future. You can point them to the article collaborated on by many awk experts at http://awk.info/?tip/getline if that helps. In this case, the correct, trivial, robust awk answer is simply `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '$1~/;0$/ || $2~/;0$/' file`.

Comment: @user1475436 If for whatever reason you don't want to treat each group of lines as a single record, you still don't need getline to employ the same style of solution as posted here: `awk -F';' 'NR%3==1{f=$NF;a=$0} NR%3==2{if(f==0||$NF==0)print a"\n"$0"\n"}' file`

Comment: I was so busy thinking about how to re-write the getline solution I missed the VERY obvious real awk solution of `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '/;0(\n|$)/' file`. I'll update my answer. Another getline caveat strikes - it gets you thinking in Algol rather than awk!

Comment: Bit rich @EdMorton considering both of your answer don't produce the required output. I don't see you mentioning the fact that setting `ORS='\n\n` adds two trailing blank lines. Believe it or not, not every user needs a *perfect, elegant, robust* solution, they are just interested in doing the transformation they need and move on, I thought you would be aware of this after seeing some your latest answers.

Comment: Setting ORS='\n\n' does NOT add 2 trailing blank lines, it adds one blank line after the final record ONLY IF there wasn't one already present after that final record in the input file. It just makes sure that the last record output follows the same rule as all of the other records by having it followed by a blank line. If that's undesirable there's various tweaks to fix it, the simplest being to use gawks RT instead of a "\n". All I'm saying is if you're going to suggest using getline then let people know what they're getting into.

Comment: One, two, semantics, I don't think It takes 3 comments to point the OP to a link about the caveats of getline, you have your own answer it doesn't need to be duplicated in comments on mine. I don't know why you and @AdrianFrühwirth are so caught up on this question, it's not even interesting.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ perl -00 -ne "print if /;0$/m;" < input
0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0

0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0

0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData3;1
```

`-00` turns on paragraph mode which sets the input record separator to `\n\n+`, so this relies on your empty lines between two data lines.

```
$ cat input
0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData1;200
0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData1;200

0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0

0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0

0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
0;Data;0;moreData;EvenMoreData3;1
```

Comment: @ikegami What other assumptions does this make than relying on the input pairs to be separated by empty lines (which seems to be the case, based on the sample) ...?

Comment: Hum, I seem to remember the question differently what how it currently stands. Nevermind. +1

Comment: (It does keep ;0 followed by not ;0, but that's probably desired.)

Comment: That's how I understood the question, even though it was not part of the sample input/output based on *"and the line above or below it"*.

Comment: I like-ed the above @sudo_O's comment about the "searching infinite factors" :) - but down-voting this answer **without explanation** what is bad is not very helpful. ;(

Comment: @cajwine voting **doesn't** required explanations, whether that be upvotes or downvote. Users have the right to vote in whatever manner they see fit. If the reason for downvoting is because the answer is flawed then a comment would be helpful but a comment for a downvoting for quality, personal preference, ect would be counter productive. Stackoverflows primary goal is too help the community not get hung up in stupid reputation wars or leaving comments trying to belittle *competing* answers. What distinguishes the downvote here compare to the one I got I wonder?

Comment: @user1475436 You state above that *"The perl works only if theirs no zeros in any of the data up to the last semi colon."*. The regex is anchored to the end of the line and I cannot reproduce this, see my updated answer. Can you provide a sample that fails with this? I'm just curious.

Comment: @sudo_O - when you hoover at the "downvote" arrow, the popup telling: _This answer if not useful_. So, it is nice to tell to the answer's author "why someone think than it is not useful". You're right, it doesn't _required_ to explain why, but it is helpful for OP and for the answer's author too. And will not commenting the "down-voting - because of _personal preference_". :( But, you're brilliantly right about the "searching infinite factors" = and I understand your point of view ;)

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth - excellent! +10 if i could. I love perl, and this is really nice example showing its power. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;N;/;0(\n|$)/p;d' file
```

Comment: What would the sed solution be if you have groups of 10 lines instead of 2?

Comment: The OP asked about the groups of 2 lines. So the answer is correct.

Comment: @EdMorton for n groups of lines use `sed -r ':a;$!{N;s/\n/&/10;Ta};/;0(\n|$)/p;d' file`. Change 10 to fit your number of lines. Of course you could repeat the `N` command `n` times as well if you prefer.

Comment: @potong - Ah, got it, thanks. I've been using sed for 30 years and couldn't have come up with that solution in your comment. I'd never suggest anyone use sed for something like this but my hat's certainly off to you for figuring it out!

Answer (score 1):

Just tell awk that records are separated by blank lines (`-v RS=`)and fields by newlines (`-F'\n'`) then check for a ";0" at the end of any line in the record:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' '/;0(\n|$)/' file
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0

Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

Setting ORS to 2 newlines (`-v ORS='\n\n'`) just tells awk to put a blank line between output records so it looks like your input format. If you don't care about that, just don't set ORS and you'll get the even simpler:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/;0(\n|$)/' file
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

FYI this will work as-is for any number of lines in your record.

In response the the comment asking for further explanation:

awk is record-based, unlike sed which is line-based. The default record separator for awk is a newline so by default awk works on lines, just like sed does, but by change the record separator (the builtin RS variable) you can have awk work on any blocks of text you like. In particular when you set RS to the NULL string then awk records are separated by blank lines.

So, in this particular case, `-v RS=` is setting RS to the NULL string so awk processes the input as 3 records:

Record 1)

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData1;200
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData1;200
```

Record 2)

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0
```

Record 3)

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

Awk by dafault breaks records into fields separate by chains of white space but you can alter that behavior by setting the built in Field Separator variable, FS. In this case I set FS to a newline by doing `-F'\n'` which means that each of the above records is treated as 2 fields:

Record 1, Field 1)

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData1;200
```

Record 1, Field 2)

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData1;200
```

Record 2, Field 1)

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
```

Record 2, Field 1)

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0
```

Record 3, Field 1)

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

Record 3, Field 2)

```
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

and now that I've got to this point I realize that I didn't need to set FS at all since the regexp i ended up with operates on the whole record not individual fields so this is actually all I needed:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/;0(\n|$)/' file
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0

Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

Which is just looking for the regexp ";0" at the end of any line as identified by "\n" (e.g. at the end of line 1 of each record) or at the end of a record as identified by "$" (e.g. at the end of line 2 of each record and so /;0(\n|$)/ will find ";0" at the end of any line in the record.

Hope that helps, and apologies for the confusion in setting FS when I didn't need to, it was an artifact from when I first started looking at this problem.

For the golfers:

```
$ awk '/;0(\n|$)/' RS= file
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;500
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData2;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
Data;moreData;EvenMoreData3;0
```

Comment: Now that is a nice awk solution, +1.

Comment: Really nice awk solution! Can you explain it for the less advanced awk users, why (how) it is works?

Comment: @jm666 I updated my answer. Basically, it does the same thing as the perl solution as far as I can tell with my limited perl knowledge.

Comment: It's practically equivalent, the only subtle difference behind the scenes is how the match is performed ("multiline match against the whole paragraph (record)" vs. "match against end of line plus end of record).